# Intersections of hypersurfaces of degree $d$ in $\mathbb CP^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is it true that every projective sub-variety of degree $d$ in $\mathbb CP^n$ is an intersection of some number of hypersurfaces of degree $d$? Is there some simple proof of this fact? (I believe this is so)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is true. The idea is as follows : suppose your variety, say $X$, has dimension $m$. For any  $(n-m-2)$-plane  $\pi \subset\mathbb{P}^n$, take the join $\langle \pi ,X\rangle$, that is, the union of the lines $\langle p ,x\rangle$ for $p\in\pi $, $x\in X$. It is easy to see that  it is a hypersurface of degree $d$ when $\pi $ is general, and that the intersection of all these hypersurfaces when $\pi $ varies is $X$.

Comment: Is there a textbook reference for this?

Comment: Just to make one comment: this result is "set-theoretic", not "scheme-theoretic".  If $X$ is smooth, the result is scheme-theoretic. (Mumford discusses this in an old paper -- forgot the reference, but Lazarsfeld's "Positivity in Algebraic Geometry" gives the Mumford reference in the discussion of C-M regularity for smooth schemes.)  For a *reducible* counterexample, consider the union of the three coordinate axes in $\mathbb{P}^3$: correct set-theoretic intersection, but wrong scheme structure at the singular point.

Comment: Just to make that last point a bit more clear, if one starts with the homogeneous coordinate ring $k[x,y,z,w]$ of $\mathbb{P}^3$, for the degree 3 closed subscheme $X$ with graded ideal $\langle xy, xz, yz \rangle$, the graded ideal generated by the degree $3$ homogeneous polynomials above is $\langle x^2y, xy^2, x^2z, xz^2, y^2z, yz^2 \rangle$, whose associated closed subscheme does not equal $X$ (although they are set-theoretically equal).